# while using df.to_json it created this character u00a0 in json how to remove in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

While using df.to_json it created this character `u00a0` in json how to remove in pandas dataframe

here is the output of the json

```
[
    {
        "dx_code":"A000",
        "formatted_code":"A00.0",
        "valid_for_coding":"0.0",
        "short_desc":null,
        "long_desc":null,
        "list_id":"Chronic_Body_Sys",
        "option_id":"1",
        "title":"Infectious and parasitic\u00a0"
    },
    {
        "dx_code":"A00",
        "formatted_code":"A00",
        "valid_for_coding":0.0,
        "short_desc":"Cholera",
        "long_desc":"Cholera",
        "list_id":"Chronic_Body_System",
        "option_id":"1",
        "title":"Infectious and parasitic disease\u00a0"
    },
    {
        "dx_code":"A000",
        "formatted_code":"A00.0",
        "valid_for_coding":1.0,
        "short_desc":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae",
        "long_desc":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae",
        "list_id":"Chronic_Body_System",
        "option_id":"1",
        "title":"Infectious and parasitic disease\u00a0"
    },
    {
        "dx_code":"A001",
        "formatted_code":"A00.1",
        "valid_for_coding":1.0,
        "short_desc":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor",
        "long_desc":"Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor",
        "list_id":"Chronic_Body_System",
        "option_id":"1",
        "title":"Infectious and parasitic disease\u00a0"
    }
}
```

this the code I used

```
testdata.to_json('testfile.json',indent=4,orient='records')
```

this \u00a0 character is not present in the data and I don't know how to remove it  any suggestion for this code I was using jupyter notebook working on a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for whitespaces we can use this code it will remove all we use is [strip()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)
like this for my question I can use this

```
testdata.title.str.strip()
#and then
testdata.to_json()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to keep this character without issue.

If really you want to remove it, remember that [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) returns a string, so you can use a simple:

```
s = df.to_json().replace('\u00a0', '')
```

###### saving to file:

```
with open('testfile.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_json(indent=4,orient='records').replace('\u00a0', ''))
```

Comment: applied your suggestion to my code `testdata.to_json('testfile.json',indent=4,orient='records').replace('\u00a0', '')` and it is giving this error what should i change here in the code
error:`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: @Siva you should **not** output to file directly, remove the `'testfile.json'`, return a string and apply the `replace` and only **then** save to file. See update.

Comment: i tried the saving to file code but it hadn't changed I did this step 1 run to_json code,2run your saving to file code but no change occured

Answer (score -1):

Looking [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), the `00a0` character is a no-break space. Using `to_json`'s `force_ascii` should turn that to a normal `\n`. Either way, deserializing (loading) this JSON should work just fine, as Python should know how to handle the character.

TL;DR
It is the unicode character for a space with no break, and is added in for formatting reasons. use `force_ascii` if you want it gone, but reading this JSON should work just fine.